# Elementor seems to be showing shortcode, not contents

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, elementor

In this Elementor-made WP website one of the pages has mutated into just its Shortcode description showing, insted of the actual contents and UI:

https://www.agenciadinamita.com/nosotros/

I have already tried to re-introduce it through both PHPmyAdmin and the Classic Editor, but that didn't work. Has this happened to anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Your website is not working based on Elementor, it is built with [Visual Composer](https://visualcomposer.com/). Install and activate it and will start working.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I did install it (developer's website is visualcomposer.com) and activated it but so far nothing has changed, even after erasing cache. Am I missing any further steps?

Comment: I can see it in view source. Are you have licenced version of the visual composer?

Answer (score 0):

The shortcodes seem coming from the Visual Composer Page Builder.  Also, your page doesn't look edited by using [elementor](https://elementor.com/) page builder on that page.
I recommend to install and activate the [Visual Composer Page Builder](https://visualcomposer.com/) plugin on the website to make this page working.

Comment: I recently did just that, but nothing changed.

Comment: Switch to default editor after installing the Visual Builder and then check your page